# pdf.image image print image same image in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, pdf, pyfpdf

I am trying to output different photos into different pdfs
but I see that it is still printing the same photo in all pdfs.

`namelist=[]` values are `['ABC1 XYZ1', 'ABC2 XYZ2', 'ABC3 XYZ3', 'ABC4 XYZ4', 'ABC5 XYZ5']`
[pics named same as in namelist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC4Lq.png)
but it still outputs only first image.  Why?
[ABC2 XYZ2.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dIB8.png)
see here in `ABC2 XYZ2.pdf`. It should output ABC2 XYZ2.jpg image.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from main import *
import os
class PDF(FPDF):
    def lines(self):
        self.set_fill_color(255,99,71) # color for outer rectangle
        self.rect(5.0, 5.0, 200.0,287.0,'DF')
        self.set_fill_color(255,255,255) # color for inner rectangle
        self.rect(8.0, 8.0, 194.0,281.0,'FD')
    
    def imagex(self,sctplt,x,y,width,height):
        self.set_xy(x,y)
        self.image(sctplt, type='', w=width, h=height)
    def titles(self):
        self.set_xy(0.0,0.0)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
        self.set_text_color(220, 50, 50)
        self.cell(w=210.0, h=40.0, align='C', txt="t", border=0)
    def texts(self,name):
        with open(name,'rb') as xy:
            txt=xy.read().decode('latin-1')
        self.set_xy(10.0,80.0)    
        self.set_text_color(76.0, 32.0, 250.0)
        self.set_font('Arial', '', 12)
        self.multi_cell(0,10,txt)
        

namelist=[]
for k in range(len(x)):
    namelist.append(x[k][0])
print(namelist)

pdf = PDF(orientation='P', unit='mm', format='A4')
pdf.add_page()
pdf.lines()
image1="wisdom test/1.png"
image2="wisdom test/2.png"
pdf.imagex(image1,89.0,10.0,2000/50,1920/50)
pdf.imagex(image2,20.0,50.0,2000/50,1920/50)

for i in range(len(namelist)):
    currstudent=namelist[i]
    pdf.imagex("pics/{}.jpg".format(currstudent),22.0,52.5,1900/60,1850/55)
    pdf.output('{}.pdf'.format(currstudent),'F')
        
    
    pdf.titles()
    pdf.output('{}.pdf'.format(currstudent),'F')
```

Comment: What is the output from `print(namelist)`?

Comment: ['ABC1 XYZ1', 'ABC2 XYZ2', 'ABC3 XYZ3', 'ABC4 XYZ4', 'ABC5 XYZ5']

Comment: `pdf.output` closes the document.  You need to call `open` or `add_page` if you're going to add more to it.

Comment: i want to make different pdfs named after namelist elements ie:['ABC1 XYZ1', 'ABC2 XYZ2', 'ABC3 XYZ3', 'ABC4 XYZ4', 'ABC5 XYZ5']

Comment: i want to make pdf ABC1 XYZ1.pdf and abc2 xyz2.pdf and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is only creating a single PDF file with one page.  If you move all of your PDF creation code inside your `for i in range(len(namelist)):` loop, you will create a separate PDF file per name in the namelist.  Something like:

```
for i in range(len(namelist)):
    pdf = PDF(orientation='P', unit='mm', format='A4')
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.lines()
    image1="wisdom test/1.png"
    image2="wisdom test/2.png"
    pdf.imagex(image1,89.0,10.0,2000/50,1920/50)
    pdf.imagex(image2,20.0,50.0,2000/50,1920/50)
    currstudent=namelist[i]
    pdf.imagex("pics/{}.jpg".format(currstudent),22.0,52.5,1900/60,1850/55)
    pdf.titles()    
    pdf.output('{}.pdf'.format(currstudent),'F')
```

I used some sample images and modified your code and I was able to generate separate PDF files, each with different images.

Pre-script run directory listing:

```
$ ls . ./images/ ./output
.:
images    output    script.py

./images/:
one.jpg         small-left.jpg  small-right.jpg three.jpg       two.jpg

./output:
```

Post-script run directory listing: (now 3 .pdf files in the output directory)

```
$ ls . ./images/ ./output
.:
images    output    script.py

./images/:
one.jpg         small-left.jpg  small-right.jpg three.jpg       two.jpg

./output:
one.pdf   three.pdf two.pdf
```

Contents of `script.py`

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import os

class PDF(FPDF):
    def lines(self):
        self.set_fill_color(255,99,71) # color for outer rectangle
        self.rect(5.0, 5.0, 200.0,287.0,'DF')
        self.set_fill_color(255,255,255) # color for inner rectangle
        self.rect(8.0, 8.0, 194.0,281.0,'FD')
    
    def imagex(self,sctplt,x,y,width,height):
        self.set_xy(x,y)
        self.image(sctplt, type='', w=width, h=height)
    def titles(self):
        self.set_xy(0.0,0.0)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
        self.set_text_color(220, 50, 50)
        self.cell(w=210.0, h=40.0, align='C', txt="t", border=0)
    def texts(self,name):
        with open(name,'rb') as xy:
            txt=xy.read().decode('latin-1')
        self.set_xy(10.0,80.0)    
        self.set_text_color(76.0, 32.0, 250.0)
        self.set_font('Arial', '', 12)
        self.multi_cell(0,10,txt)

for name in ["one", "two", "three"]:
    pdf = PDF(orientation='P', unit='mm', format='A4')
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.lines()
    pdf.imagex("images/small-left.jpg",89.0,10.0,2000/50,1920/50)
    pdf.imagex("images/small-right.jpg",20.0,50.0,2000/50,1920/50)
    pdf.imagex(f"images/{name}.jpg",22.0,52.5,1900/60,1850/55)
    pdf.titles()
    pdf.output(f"output/{name}.pdf",'F')
```